# Showing six latest PhpBB posts instead of six copies of latest post

Tags: php, forum, phpbb

Trying to display six of the latest posts from my PhpBB installation. I'm happy with how it's all working, however it's showing six copies of the same (most recent) post, and not size unique latest posts.

Just to confirm, I have seven total posts on the forums.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpass", "dbname");

$users = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM phpbb_user_group WHERE group_id='8'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users)) {
        $developers[] = $row["user_id"];
}

$post = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM phpbb_posts");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($post)) {
        $topic_id = $row["topic_id"];
        $forum_id = $row["forum_id"];
        $post_id = $row["post_id"];
        $post_text = $row["post_text"];
        $post_time = $row["post_time"];
}

$username = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM phpbb_users WHERE user_id='2'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($username)) {
        $postauthor = $row["username"];


if (strlen($post_text) > 10)   
    $post_text = wordwrap($post_text, 120);
    $post_text = explode("\n", $post_text);
    $post_text = $post_text[0] . '...';

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM phpbb_posts WHERE poster_id='2' LIMIT 6");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $content = '<div onclick="location.href=\'http://test.mythros.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=' . $forum_id .     '&amp;p=' . $topic_id . '#p' . $post_id . '\';" class="forum-latest-box">';
        $content .=     '<div class="forum-latest-userbar">';
        $content .=                     '<div class="forum-latest-avatar">';
        $content .=                              '<img src="https://minotar.net/helm/' . $postauthor . '/40.png">';
        $content .=                      '</div>';
        $content .=                      '<h1>' . $postauthor . '</h1>';
        $content .=              '</div>';
        $content .=              '<div class="forum-latest-content">';
        $content .=                      '<div class="forum-latest-text">';
        $content .=                              '"' . $post_text . '"';
        $content .=                      '</div>';
        $content .=                      '<div class="forum-latest-meta">';
        $content .=                              gmdate("F j, Y, g:i a", $post_time);
        $content .=                      '</div>';
        $content .=              '</div>';
        $content .=     '</div>';
        echo $content;
}

?>
```

Comment: Look at your loops in more detail, particularly the loop where you're going through posts to print them. On that loop, you want to get the information about the author, do the various bits of text transformation, and then print out the resulting post. Where is `$post_text` coming from? When did you set it? Is it printing out what you think it is printing out?

Comment: @ialarmedalien
    $post_text
is coming from
    $post_text = $row["post_text"];

Which pulls the phpbb post's text from the database. It seems to be displaying things as I want them, just all six 'entries' are showing the same post's information.

Comment: Look at the loop where $post_text, etc., are being set; it is going through all the posts on the forum and setting those variables to the appropriate values. However, it is only saving the data from the *last* post, because each loop overwrites the data from the previous loop. Do you understand the problem now?

Comment: Ahh I see! So How would I go about correctly looping this? I understand the issue in theory but have no clue what would be at fault in the code.

Comment: The easiest thing would be to eliminate the first loop and change your query to select the 6 most recent posts from phpbb_posts, do the text transformations, and then print out the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using a single loop and getting your post data and user information at the same time using combined query to the `phpbb_posts` table and `phpbb_users` table:

```
## Line break added to the query for legibility
$result = mysqli_query($con,
"SELECT
    p.post_id AS post_id,
    p.topic_id AS topic_id,
    p.forum_id AS forum_id,
    p.post_time AS post_time, 
    p.post_subject AS subject,
    p.post_text AS post_text
    IFNULL(m.username, 'Guest') AS username,
    FROM phpbb_posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN phpbb_users AS m ON (m.user_id = p.poster_id)
    ORDER BY phpbb_posts.post_time DESC LIMIT 6");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
# $row now contains the post information and the user info, so you can grab all your data,
# process the post text, and print it out at the same time.
    $post_text = $row["post_text"];
    # do your text transformation
    if (strlen($post_text) > 10)
    ... (etc.)
    # now set up your content
    $content = '<div onclick="location.href=\'http://test.mythros.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=' . $row["forum_id"] .'&amp;p=' . $row["topic_id"] . '#p' . $row["post_id"] . '\';" class="forum-latest-box">';
    ... (etc.)

}
```

Comment: Very nice! Never really looked into combined queries before. Very helpful! +1